# How can I compare PHP variable with a modal id?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some Categories. When I will click on a category, then all of it's sub categories will be shown in a Bootstrap Modal.

```
<p data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$category['id']}}" data-target="#subcategory_Modal">{{$category['name']}}</p>
```

I am passing the category id with `data-id`. Main Category has parent id 0. And sub category has a value of parent_id.

Now, How can I compare my passing ID: `data-id` with the parent_id which I am getting from database with Laravel/PHP.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @if(!empty($category['sub_categories']))
      @foreach($category['sub_categories'] as $sc)
          @php($parent_id_of_sc = $sc['parent_id'])
              @if($parent_id_of_sc==id) //like this
                 <p><button>{{$sc['name']}}</button></p>
              @endif
      @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Please check my code. I am getting all parent ids from this loop.I have to compare with the Modal Data ID which I have passed with Modal.

Comment: Where do you want to compare them, PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: In the Laravel blade file. Inside @foreach above code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Laravel person, but comparing a string extracted from the DOM with the value of a PHP variable means sending the string to the server first.

You can do this by grabbing the string value from `data-id` using `ELement.getAttribute("data-id")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

```
let category = document.getELementById("yourElementId").getAttribute("data-id")
```

or

```
var category = document.getELementById("yourElementId").getAttribute("data-id")
```

Then, find a way to send it to your PHP applicaton, usually by AJAX (with the XmlHttpRequest object) or some other means.